# Android ListView multiple images in one item

Tags: android, image, listview

How can I implement the following feature: each item of a `ListView` may contain several Images and the number of Images may vary.

for example 
[Example of such listView](http://pikucha.ru/idTSN)

Comment: And where may I create imageViews, in the getview function of adapter? The number of images for each item is different. I guess it will work slowly, because for each item I should create imageViews.

Comment: Thank you! But I still doubt that it will work quickly and correctly, because I should programmatically create multimple ImageViews for every item. And than these ImageViews will not be reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override the `getView` method in your custom adapter for the listview. 
Depending on the number of images add them dynamically.

something similar to the below code

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
if( convertView == null ){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
}
//images is a array of bitmap here
for(int i =0;i<images.length;i++){
   ImageView img = new ImageView(getContext());
   img.setImageBitmap(images[i]);
   convertView.add(img);
}

return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom adapter for that.
You can search for List view custom adapter and there are tons of blog about it.
Like [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple!
1.Create your custom row layout
2.Add imageviews to your row programmatically inside adapter getView method